# typescript losing precision when intersecting discriminated union

Tags: typescript

I have the following discriminated union type.

```
enum EventType {
  PostCreated = "POST_CREATED",
  UserCreated = "USER_CREATED",
}

type Event =
  | { type: EventType.PostCreated, data: { postId: number } }
  | { type: EventType.UserCreated, data: { userId: number } }
```

I want to create the type signature for a function that uses a `type` parameter to check a `data` parameter.

```
function createEvent<Type extends Event["type"]>(
  type: Type,
  data: (Event & { type: Type })["data"],
): Event {
  // ...
}
```

However the `data` parameter always includes all values from the union (as though I'd written `Event["data"]` instead). The initial intersection (`Event & { type: Type }`) seems to work, so what's going on here?

Additional context and test cases are here [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQAKA9gM6IDCATsAIaLAAmUAvFAESEDyAysgPoUASjACCyGABF2AGnxQAqqWBVqdBszbsFPGEMEjxU2bgC+uXIgxZ4SVvIA+OKFcwAuWAhAprAOhLkavRMMlCM9LQe2FDoZIgAkowe4BAARipQppmOzq7AHrbeaJi+SipBGqHhiJHOYMpUicmQ6VSZ2bgA9J1QAOLAiFC0IFDAXoMAZlTE0IgAFlhgIACWxCChAObLXkMu1pbWnkgAYtMQxcAAPBejAB4MIIykR94A2ux57AC6AHysUAAKQqDABkuWsHhupgAlABuCzdKAUYhUGgAY0QABtUFBlt4VMoMc9EMQoBM8cwIPQ0XM8RsoEtViMIMA0ipcJiBkMCuNTjMLpdgRd-HEKkw-mw8AQ8jykMKApQaMFGHICNVatFYuQmlAAIwAJgAzJk5KZ4V0esjUcAMdjRqiUaRQiSoKQ5sQAO4uOb0MIRGLTTBUKy4554tEo9GIDlc1Ky7x887WQXjeWipUaCU4eQyl4+EoKsUq+SIgACiFIAFpgLdMBjqw6qPJ1VEGQ0dQbjaZTea8nnJBFEwKbjWHk88+9Pr9-sCh8mLj93urvubEfEQBHrbacbRMZjPc9d5ioHBd2BgM8pjMJ+xl18Y4M0fHEAOanPMCm5X5Cxnxf9NXEHZGpk8JlhW1a1jaiANtMTacoMST9oOZwCkK37puof6Sm2KhAV25oWlAyC0s8NCIGAVAgMSCxQJuUZ7JgByYLAty6jOvIocmaEFhhyo-KuPTxBMUAelgTE2Lc+rsScnEftxwAioEv6MIut4RCuCI9AAQmAgy0M8pDEGsQzPKJJkANZkiiuzoIGKhWKEZn7soAY2sspBMuJLHGmwwKvrQ75XPJimKphKkCXmYBHqgoTxCJwyDC6HpUMsDC7BMSwYky3q+jSNrmdRWDqkMVAbJASCbNsoC7KQdbLOSaIMQphEABIqFgtA0K6MxYBMtDLJyzD0AwEDoBWbgWIwNqYp1vWZYg2Vor+wKiIKdxjs8wI-ACOYQrAk7WN8qp+jUBRLupXxyNCz7mlNaIzV1GUbgtxlLZhwJadchyjqA47AgdmDfNtu3uER1jHS2eaBV9mCqXeuDXXmEXllWNZ1tBKiwVAlauu6YCYsw6QxIBzAgMQgz1LhjC4G9wQrUCqboUpYWhNElONIhUkwsj4Fo1BMEojTy3jFpDNfjxzPKqzOEcx4XNwppRE0WsdoerQOJxWiwxQFS5lYKlIkopZhlkp1oTuS4pKU7sVLoOgdJQFQ9ALG08za7QDIrGsFh9sCzySvIrzBT+YVfK2WoJIhKStCBgfBWUqjKWHdTtlHLQZGaZi3dNs1kvNi3C0gFAw1gP2PM8euoMQwl+8D0p7RcEMRM+pCvBcl0IzdisoxB6MC02tMMMCFBi0UTOhVLKdU3LmQK7gaMooM2CmEAA).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQAKA9gM6IDCATsAIaLAAmUAvFAESEDyAysgPoUASjACCyGABF2AGnxQAqqWBVqdBszbsFPGEMEjxU2bgC+Ably5EGLCXJr6TeElY4oNzAC5YCEClsAOntKGidGGShGelofbCh0MkQASUYfcAgAIxUoU1zLTywlFUcNF383eMKfcoDMQOLVMI1I6MRY9zBlKlT0yGyqXPyrQt8kAFladEr5AG1atHqQ0qYAXR9l5uc-RDkCeZ3F4AbulcZ1xVOtxlq5CytGYABjABtaGigAMzAQJ8QAS2IICgTy2tQAPMgoMAAB4MECMUhjfxHSIwaFw0CI5GISboWbIVYAPgAFPICNUoMg9gQojEarMAORtWiM1ZyACUNUsuFB6mAtRJCyCm35EXciXIvSgACZchzLHynILhfVGmdIvEuippXLTAqrAB6Q1QAACiFIAFpYZg-taqFRiFReWCdkLDiKkhrOt1dfLLMazRbrTDbYh7Y7nUqGCqPWqrmLNQkkn79ZYgA)).

```
enum EventType {
  PostCreated = "POST_CREATED",
  UserCreated = "USER_CREATED",
};

type PostCreatedEvent = { type: EventType.PostCreated, data: { postId: number } };
type UserCreatedEvent = { type: EventType.UserCreated, data: { userId: number } };

type EventMap = {
  [EventType.PostCreated]: PostCreatedEvent,
  [EventType.UserCreated]: UserCreatedEvent,
};

declare function createEvent<T extends EventType, E extends EventMap[T]>(
    type: T,
    data: E['data'],
): E;

createEvent(EventType.PostCreated, { postId: 2 });
createEvent(EventType.UserCreated, { userId: 2 });

// @ts-expect-error
createEvent(EventType.PostCreated, { userId: 2 });
// @ts-expect-error
createEvent(EventType.UserCreated, { postId: 2 });
```

Comment: Thanks. The `EventType` enum is actually much bigger in practice so manually writing all conditional branches isn't an appealing option. I already have a working variation, but I'm much more interested in why the above doesn't work.

Comment: For sure—wasn't a fan of the ternaries myself. Have updated to use a map instead 

Comment: The original attempt didn't work because of strangeness in the generics used in the `createEvent` implementations (they didn't quite line up). Note the use of `E extends EventType, T extends EventMap[E]` in the solution above.

Comment: What was strange about the generics in the original attempt? My playground link already had a solution that solves the problem using maps, but I still don't understand why the union approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your type `type EventFromType<Type extends Event["type"]> = (Event & { type: Type });` eventually is represented as:

```ts
type EventFromType<Type extends EventType> = {
    type: EventType.PostCreated & Type;
    data: {
        postId: number;
    };
} | {
    type: EventType.UserCreated & Type;
    data: {
        userId: number;
    };
}
```

So, while you're passing concrete types to `EventDataFromType` it gets evaluated to correct results. But when you make *generic* lookup by `"data"` it stops being dependent on `type` field anymore:

```ts
type EventDataFromType<Type extends EventType> = ({
    type: EventType.PostCreated & Type;
    data: {
        postId: number;
    };
} | {
    type: EventType.UserCreated & Type;
    data: {
        userId: number;
    };
})["data"]

// <=>

type EventDataFromType<Type extends EventType> = {
    postId: number;
} | {
    userId: number;
}
```

To mitigate that behavior you should make `EventFromType` evaluated lazyly. To  evaluate the result type only when it's provided with a concrete type:

```ts
type EventFromType<Type extends Event["type"]> = 
    Type extends unknown ? (Event & { type: Type }) : never;
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL9KaW)

Then everything works as expected.

---

### Update on `extends unknown`:

To understand why it works this way let's introduce `Id<T>` type to eagerly evaluate fields of the `T` type:

```ts
type Id<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
```

First let's look what's happening inside original `EventFromType` type:

```ts
type EventFromTypeEval<Type extends Event["type"]> = Id<Event & { type: Type }>

type EventFromTypeEval<Type extends EventType> = {
    type: EventType.PostCreated & Type;
    data: {
        postId: number;
    };
} | {
    type: EventType.UserCreated & Type;
    data: {
        userId: number;
    };
}
```

Looks like the type has no unknown (pun intended) types in it's structure and gets eagerly evaluated right away. `Event` and `Type extends Event["type"]` has all known and very limited number of habitants. That explains why *generic* lookup by `data` field just strips away all `type` fields.

To make it evaluate lazyly we have to inject some uncertainty.

```ts
type EventFromTypeLazy<Type extends Event["type"]> = 
    Type extends unknown ? Event & { type: Type } : never
```

And `T extends unknown` is a perfect candidate here. While any type `T` is a subset of `unknown` and will fall through into the truthy arm of the condition, it may aswell be a *union* type and typescript will have to process it as [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Typescript cannot simply discard `extends unknown`. It has to wait for concrete type and only then evaluate the result type. Let's look inside the result of `Id<T>`:

```ts
type EventFromTypeLazyEval<Type extends Event["type"]> = 
    Id<Type extends unknown ? Event & { type: Type } : never>

type EventFromTypeLazyEval<Type extends EventType> = (Type extends unknown ? Event & {
    type: Type;
} : never) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K]; } : never
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/ND5blm)

No eager evaluation here. Typescript keeps the type opaque untill the concrete `Type` is provided.

Comment: Super interesting—that works well, but the solution isn't intuitive. Do you have any other info for why the `unknown` conditional type works here? Haven't come across this type of problem in TS before.

Comment: It's just creating some sort of `thunk` or type-level function expecting an argument. Contrary to the case when it has all types available and can evaluate and optimize them as it in fact does.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow. I recognise `EventFromType` as a type-level function expecting an argument (`Type`) but the `Type extends unknown` is the conditional that I'm finding confusing.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the lazy evaluation, but `Type extends unknown` doesn't seem like an intuitive check. Isn't `unknown` a super type of almost all other types?